# PreferenceFragment faults on id.list but not on id.content

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferences

What I really want to do is add a preference screen to an existing layout with other items in it (such as a button) without using deprecated approaches. I have looked at the 'add button to preference screen' and I get that to semi-work using deprecated approaches.

I have two xml layouts. First the preference screen (at the moment the PreferenceCategory is superfluous) with 12 other CheckBoxPreferences omitted for clarity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="@string/specialization_prefs"
    android:title="@string/select_specializations">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/pulse_ox_key"
        android:title="@string/pulse_ox"
        android:defaultValue="true" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/bp_key"
        android:title="@string/bp"
        android:defaultValue="true" />

 </PreferenceCategory>
```

Then I have the activity layout (PreferenceActivity or Activity; does not seem to matter):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/specializations_layout" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Exit and Save" />

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView was meant to be a dummy to be replaced with the PreferenceFragment which I got from a Stackoverflow suggestion. The Button I want to keep.

My PreferenceFragment is as follows:

```
public class SpecializationsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity specializationsActivity)
    {
        super.onAttach(specializationsActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.specializations);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Finally my PreferenceActivity is as follows:

```
public class SpecializationsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.specializations_layout);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.list, new SpecializationsFragment())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

If I replace the 'android.R.id.list' with 'android.R.id.content' it sort of works. I see my button but my preference screen scrolls right over it. This is what I get when I follow the deprecated button solution. If I use the 'android.R.id.list' instead, the application crashes saying "addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView.

I have searched on that problem as well. What am I missing? This code currently does nothing but a GUI display. What do I need to add to get the button to display and the preference screen to scroll in the space below it as it is supposed to do in its own 'fragment'? I thought that was the whole idea behind fragments. (Yes they actually work quite well as long as preference screens are not present.) It also makes no difference using the 'add' method versus the 'replace' method.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who cares I found a solution. Not what I expected but it worked. First I needed to nest a layout within my layout. Then I needed to align this nested layout below the button. I also needed to have the dummy ListView in there but I do not know why. So the xml appears as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Exit and Save" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/specializations_layout" >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code now has the replace method (using 'add' or 'replace' made no difference) using the id added to the nested relative layout as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.specializations_layout);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.specializations_layout, new SpecializationsFragment())
            .commit();
    findViewById(android.R.id.list).setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

I don't understand what is going on under the hood here, especially with the need for the dummy  element and its android:id/list attribute. I would like to have seen it work without the ListView element as I believe would be the case if this was an ordinary fragment and not a preference screen. I would be grateful to anyone who can explain this to me!

Comment: I probably understand even less about what's going on than you, but my guess is that the fragment manager wants to replace/fill preferences of a layout, not a list element which is what you (and I) were trying to do. Strangely, it didn't work with a LinearLayout (all I got was a blank screen) but Relative worked. I was also able to add a floating button using a top-level android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout. With that said, your solution worked for me so you should accept it as the answer.

Comment: Also, this is the best way I have found so far on SO to add a button to a preference screen or fragment (whether floating or not). And the only one that worked for showing both the button and the preference screen (I have a couple items pre-filled and needed to add more dynamically). Hoping future searches will guide people to this page.